# writing in a file using C# StreamWriter

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I was practicing to write into a file using c#

my code is not working (writing in file is not done)

```
{
    int T, N; //T = testCase , N = number of dice in any Test
    int index = 0, straight;
    List<string> nDiceFaceValues = new List<string>(); //List for Dice Faces
    string line = null;  //string to read line from file
    string[] lineValues = {};  //array of string to split string line values

    string InputFilePath = @ "E:\Visual Studio 2017\CodeJam_Dice Straight\A-small-practice.in"; //path of input file
    string OuputFilePath = @
    "E:\Visual Studio 2017\CodeJam_Dice Straight\A-small-practice.out"; //path of otput file

    StreamReader InputFile = new StreamReader(InputFilePath);
    StreamWriter Outputfile = new StreamWriter(OuputFilePath);

    T = Int32.Parse(InputFile.ReadLine());  //test cases input
    Console.WriteLine("Test Cases : {0}", T);

    while (index < T) {
        N = Int32.Parse(InputFile.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            line = InputFile.ReadLine();
            lineValues = line.Split(' ');

            foreach(string j in lineValues)
            {
                nDiceFaceValues.Add(j);
            }
        }
        straight = ArrangeDiceINStraight(nDiceFaceValues);
        Console.WriteLine("case:  {0} , {1}", ++index, straight);

        Outputfile.WriteLine("case:  {0} , {1}", index, straight);
        nDiceFaceValues.Clear();
    }
}
```

what is wrong with this code?

how I fix it?

why its not working??

Note:  I want to write in file line by line

Comment: wrap up the streamwriter in a using statement. Currently you are not closing the file stream and you are never saving the file

Comment: Please try to provide a full example of your method if possible.

Comment: You are getting an error, but you don't tell us the error.

Comment: I did not face any error, but when i run the program, it runs fine, on console it shows result but not write in file

Comment: But the first two words in your title are "facing error".

Comment: Why does the title say "facing error" but your comment says you aren't facing an error?  Which is it?

Comment: O sorry, next time i will be very careful

Comment: @Fahad I'm asking about *this time*.  Please answer our questions.  Which is it?  Are you getting an error or not?

Comment: now I am not getting any error, there was a problem with my code, i was not using append command to append the file second time, when i write the command, then my problem is solved. thank you all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's *missing* is: closing things down - flushing the buffers, etc:

```
using(var outputfile = new StreamWriter(ouputFilePath)) {
    outputfile.WriteLine("case:  {0} , {1}", index, straight);
}
```

However, if you're going to do that for every line, `File.AppendText` may be more convenient.

In particular, note that `new StreamWriter` will be *overwriting* by default, so you'd also need to account for that:

```
using(var outputfile = new StreamWriter(ouputFilePathm, true)) {
    outputfile.WriteLine("case:  {0} , {1}", index, straight);
}
```

the `true` here is for `append`.

If you have opened a file for concurrent read/write, you could also *try* just adding `outputfile.Flush();`, but... it isn't guaranteed to do anything.

Comment: i update my code in my question, please see it again

Comment: Thanks..  It was very helpful

Comment: Kindly tell me one more thing?

Comment: Why we are using <using> clause here?

Comment: @Fahad `using` is a way of invoking `Dispose()`; it is `Dispose()` that flushes all the buffers and makes sure that any buffered data is actually written to the file, making the file available for read again. In some cases you *can* get by via just `Flush()`, YMMV